# Is changing a parameter in a OperationContract to it's Nullable<T> equivalent considered a breaking change?

Tags: c#, wcf, servicecontract

Consider the following `ServiceContract`-Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MyMethod(int a, int b);
}
```

Now we change it to the following (effectively changing parameter `int a` to a `int? a`):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MyMethod(int? a, int b);
}
```

Would a client consuming this WCF-Service need to make additional changes to work with the new service definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had time to test everything and figured out my own answer.

It is **not** a breaking change for the following frameworks:

- .NET (C#, 4.5)
- Java 8

I did not test anything else as it doesn't matter for our scenario.

This means every client still works (without regenerating the client) even after updating the web service definition